# Cannot access memory at address 0x48e7458d48c38958 with gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I am new to gdb and am using gdb to debug a project written by others. In this piece:

```
int CObjectRecognizer::String2StructInput(const StructInstanceInput &input, StructAlgoResult &aResult, SObjectRecInput &inputInfo)
{
    try
    {
        map<string,string> inputmap = input.field;
        if(inputmap.find("att") != inputmap.end())
        {
            inputInfo.m_att = atoi(inputmap["att"].c_str());
        }
}
```

In gdb, I want to check the value of inputmap, but it gives an error message:

```
(gdb) next
899         map<string,string> inputmap = input.field;
(gdb) print inputmap
$1 = std::map with 140737488343904 elements<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x48e7458d48c38958>
(gdb)
```

Why can't it access memory at the particular address 0x48e7458d48c38958?

EDIT: following suggestion:

```
(gdb) print inputmap
$2 = std::map with 0 elements
```

It seems the map is empty. Why doesn't this line create a map?:

```
map<string,string> inputmap = input.field;
```

Comment: Run `next` and try printing again. The map is not yet constructed at this point, so no surprise it contains garbage.

Comment: please see my addition. Why doesn't the assignment 'inputmap = input.field' create a map?

Comment: It's an initialization, not an assignment. The map was created, it's just empty. It means `input.field` also was empty.

Comment: And if you're not sure why something initialized from the input is whatever it is, you should probably try printing `input`. Go exploring.

Comment: Why you believe that a map with 140737488343904 elements can be valid :-) Looks like you already found the bug if you get that info from gdb. You are simply looking on a destructed or non initialized data structure or a pointer or reference pointing to such thing.

Answer (score 1):

When a GDB line or function entry breakpoint is hit, or when you use the `step` or `next` commands, the target program is stopped at the beginning of the first statement of a line, **before any code in that line has been executed.**

This behavior is usually exactly what you want, for example if your program has a line `a[i+j] = b[i] + c[j];` and you want to check for an array out-of-bounds access before it happens.

In your case, the line's statement declares an object whose address is known but whose contents won’t be defined until after the statement has been executed, including the call to its initializer. So `print` at this point shows the contents of the object’s known, but uninitialized, memory.

As @HolyBlackCat suggested in a comment, you can type `next`, and GDB will execute the current line's statement or statements, including any initializers and function calls, and stop just before the next line of source code to be executed in the current function<sup>[1]</sup>.
At that point, `print inputmap` will show the correct value<sup>[2]</sup>.

[1] or its caller, if you're at a return statement

[2] assuming it wasn’t a return statement